# Open Camera in a Custom view

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I want to implement a mechanism that lets users, just after launching the application, open camera in a custom view.

For that, I used the AVCam example provided by Apple available [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html). But it doesn't work properly.
I'll explain more by images:

What I need is that :

[image: Concept]

What I actually have is that :

[image: Bounds problem]

What I need is really to fill the all view (to have a square image).

Will that be possible using the AVFoundation Framework ?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIImagePickerController` with a custom view. Setup your custom view to appear as you need it, and use the `cameraOverlayView` to add it to the image picker. Remember to set `showsCameraControls` to `NO` to remove native controls.

When tapping your camera button, call the picker's `takePicture` method to take the picture.

Comment: Thank's for your answer I'll test it and I'll give you a feed back.